# pandas calculate row values as function of previous values in same and previous row

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a table like this

```
       A  B  C  D  E
row1   1  2  3  4  5
row2   5  6  7  8  9
```

I would like to calculte row3 as row1 shifted(1, axis=1) + row2 - value in row3 shifted(1, axis=1) [this is the previous calculated price, the cell at the left]
It would be the same than applying the following formulas in Excel

```
A3 = A2
B3 = A1 + B2 - A3
C3 = B2 + C2 - B3
[and so on]
```

The result must be calculated in one operation and the ouput should be like this one:

```
       A  B  C  D  E
row1   1  2  3  4  5
row2   5  6  7  8  9
row3   5  2  7  4  9
```

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself yet. In pandas you can access a single cell value also so you can try looping may be and see if it works

Comment: @ArpitSolanki how can I access to a single cell value in a similar way than Excel?

Comment: You can read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) a little bit long but will give a lots of insights about how to solve your problem

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the equation of C3, I suppose it should be `C3 = B1 + C2 - B3`, is that correct?

Comment: @O.Suleiman You are right. The "shifted" sense was wrong in my explanation. I already fixed it. The "Excel-like" formulas are the good ones.

Comment: I think [pandas rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arpit mentioned in the comments you can use a `for` loop and `iloc` to achieve what you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO('''A  B  C  D  E
1  2  3  4  5
5  6  7  8  9'''),sep='\s+')

df.loc[2,'A'] = 5

for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[2,i] = df.iloc[0,i-1] + df.iloc[1,i] - df.iloc[2,i-1]
```

Output:

```
In [43]: df

Out[43]:

    A   B   C   D   E
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
1   5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
2   5.0 2.0 7.0 4.0 9.0
```

Comment: And could it be done using the labels for the rows 'row1', 'row2'? I mean using `.loc` instead of `.iloc` where possible.

Comment: I am using `iloc` to be able to select the columns by their index, therefore, even if the row index was changed to 'row1', 'row2' ... etc., you will still need to use `iloc`, or else, you will have to explicitly assign each column's 3rd-row value in a single line of code, e.g. `df.loc['row3','B'] = df.loc['row1','A'] + df.loc['row2','B'] - df.loc['row3','A']`, and that is tidious. If you want to change the index, you can always do: `df.index = ['row1','row2','row3']`.